# Rolling up multiple rows with different values Into Single Row

Tags: sql

I'm trying to aggregate rows to one row with one name and the count is the sum of all rows, for example, let's say I have this table:

| type | count |
| --- | --- |
| PERSONAL_COMPUTER | 20 |
| SMARTPHONE | 10 |
| TABLET | 5 |
| SMART_TV | 10 |
| OTHER | 10 |
| UNKNOWN | 20 |
| NULL | 10 |

I want to change it to:

| type | count |
| --- | --- |
| PERSONAL_COMPUTER | 20 |
| SMARTPHONE | 10 |
| TABLET | 5 |
| SMART_TV | 10 |
| OTHER | 40 |

the "OTHER" will include OTHER, UNKNOWN and NULL values

I tried union all but I'm not getting the expected result

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: Hint: `case` expression, `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by preparing your type list first using `case when`, then applying the aggregate function `sum()` on this generated dataset:

```
select type, sum(count) as count
from (
     select case when type is null or type in ('OTHER', 'UNKNOWN') then 'OTHER' else type end as type, count
     from mytable
) t
group by type
```

Result :

```
type                count
PERSONAL_COMPUTER   20
SMARTPHONE          10
TABLET              5
SMART_TV            10
OTHER               40
```

This query is valid for both `mysql` and `sqlite`

[Demo in mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/NK59Dzwo)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to retrieve the data, without changing the underlying table, you could use

```
SELECT
  IF(type = 'UNKNOWN' OR type IS NULL, 'OTHER', type) AS type,
  SUM(count) AS count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY IF(type = 'UNKNOWN' OR type IS NULL, 'OTHER', type)
```

This works on MySQL and SQLite (thanks @jarlh for confirming)

Comment: Is this for MySQL and/or SQLite?

Comment: Works on MySQL, I'm not sure about SQLite

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Y82vdaMV, it does!

Answer (score 0):

You can make in two steps

```
UPDATE tab1
SET `count` = (SELECT SUM(`count`) FROM (SELECT `count` FROM tab1 WHERE `type` IN ( 'OTHER','UNKNOWN') OR type is NULL) t  )
  WHERE type = 'OTHER'
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
DELETE FROM  tab1 WHERE type = 'UNKNOWN' Or type is  NULL
```

```
SELECt * FROM tab1
```

| type | count |
| --- | --- |
| PERSONAL_COMPUTER | 20 |
| SMARTPHONE | 10 |
| TABLET | 5 |
| SMART_TV | 10 |
| OTHER | 40 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6F5L9esp)

And for sqllite

```
UPDATE tab1
SET `count` = (SELECT SUM(count) FROM (SELECT count FROM tab1 WHERE type IN ( 'OTHER','UNKNOWN') OR type is NULL) t  )
  WHERE type = 'OTHER'
```

```
DELETE FROM  tab1 WHERE type = 'UNKNOWN' Or type is  NULL
```

```
SELECt * FROM tab1
```

| type | count |
| --- | --- |
| PERSONAL_COMPUTER | 20 |
| SMARTPHONE | 10 |
| TABLET | 5 |
| SMART_TV | 10 |
| OTHER | 40 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ayQW8aYf)